# HTML, how do I know the height of a "textbox"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of html like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}
.mypara {
    font-family: "Segeo UI";
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 24px; 
    line-height: 120px; /* same as line-height:5 */
}
.myspan { 
    border: 6px solid #8f8; 
}
.alignmark {
    position: fixed;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    left: 0px; 
    width: 250px;
    top: 48px;
    height: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="mypara"><span class="myspan">My paragraph .</span></p>

<div class="alignmark"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I know the exact height(pixel count) of a textbox of a text line, either with JavaScript or by Chrome/Firefox DevTools(F12)?

The textbox height is the height of the area surrounded by a `<span>` element's *border* (the "border" in HTML box model).

From my experiments, the difference between **textbox height** and **font-size value** varies according to font-family I choose, some may be 5~6 pixels, some maybe 7~8 pixels.

[image: Image showing my question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `.getBoundingClientRect().height` and take away the top and bottom border size (as it's hard coded at 6 each just take away 12 - or you can use getComputedStyle and get the computed values if you wish, as below)

```js
let e = document.querySelector('.myspan');
let css = window.getComputedStyle(e);
console.log(
  e.getBoundingClientRect().height 
  - parseFloat(css.borderTopWidth) 
  - parseFloat(css.borderBottomWidth)
);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}
.mypara {
    font-family: "Segeo UI";
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 24px; 
    line-height: 120px; /* same as line-height:5 */
}
.myspan { 
    border: 6px solid #8f8;
    
}
.alignmark {
    position: fixed;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    left: 0px; 
    width: 250px;
    top: 48px;
    height: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="mypara"><span class="myspan">My paragraph .</span></p>

<div class="alignmark"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, this is the correct and pixel perfect answer. Anyway, I just can't imagine why there were so many confident people with their but wrong answers. To prove them right or wrong, it just costs less one minute in front of a computer.

Comment: @Jaromanda X                                            
Above program is showing 26 in Chrome developer tools.Where is 26 in css?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Window.getComputedStyle()` and access `fontSize` property of that.

```js
let p = document.querySelector('.mypara')
let height = window.getComputedStyle(p).fontSize

console.log(height)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}
.mypara {
    font-family: "Segeo UI";
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 24px; 
    line-height: 120px; /* same as line-height:5 */
}
.myspan { 
    border: 6px solid #8f8; 
}
.alignmark {
    position: fixed;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    left: 0px; 
    width: 250px;
    top: 48px;
    height: 24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="mypara"><span class="myspan">My paragraph .</span></p>

<div class="alignmark"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: isn't the height 28px though? according to (firefox) developer tools it is - what you've shown is the font size, which isn't the same

Comment: Apparent wrong answer, `window.getComputedStyle(p).fontSize` returns 24, which is smaller than the textbox height.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use clientHeight

```
let alignmark = document.getElementsByClassName('alignmark')[0];
console.log(alignmark.clientHeight);
```

or open Chrome Developer Tools, Select your Element via 'Elements' tab, and click the 'Properties'. You can check various DOM properties as well.

Comment: anyway, your code is measuring the `alignment` element - which is nothing to do with the span element

Answer (score 0):

This works if i have understand correctly what do you want to do.

```
 <script>
 window.onload = function(){
    console.log("Element Height:"+document.getElementById('myspan').offsetHeight);
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: and what is the answer?

Comment: I mean what is the result of this answer

Comment: Element Height:29